# How to read the contents of single post through RSS feed

Tags: jquery, rss, feed, mobile

I am able to fetch the contents of my WordPress site RSS feed through [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/) on my mobile website.

How can I get the contents of a single post through RSS?

Comment: Are you developing your own RSS reader?  I think that is out of scope for this site.

Comment: no Actually i have two websites one is in wordpress and the other is in plain PHP. Now i want to read the RSS feed from my wordpress and display the posts on my PHP website.

Comment: Then this is definitely out of scope for this site.  Try [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).